# Use an anchor tag for form post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, modal-window

I have this:

**HTML**

This is a button which opens the href in a modal window:

```
<a class="iframe button pink" href="http://www.test.php" > Pay Now <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.fethr.com/clients/res/buttonmodal.css">
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" />
<input type="text" name="xx" />
<input type="text" name="yy" />


 <a class="iframe button pink" href="http://www.test.php" > Pay Now <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.fethr.com/clients/res/buttonmodal.css">
    <script src="http://www.fethr.com/clients/res/buttonmodal.js"></script></a>

</form>
```

This anchor button.  If I click on it, it opens the href in a modal window.  I'm trying to use this as the submit button and post the values to the href as well as open it in the modal window.  Is this possible?

Comment: What you are trying to do inside that poor `a` tag is a crime to humanity....

Comment: @RCorrie I want to embedd it at any website,thats why so much scripts and all.The script it for the jquery modal window,and css for the same

Comment: Can you explain further? I'm not sure what you are trying to do, sorry

Comment: What does the link and script tags in an anchor ??? An anchor is not a head section, it's not a submit button. You could submit the FORM to this specific action... just call submit() on the form with jQuery.

Comment: @Rcorrie I actually need to post some parameters to that url.The url in the href is a payment form.So the have to post some parameters like 'amount' , 'name', etc to the payment form and as well open it in a jquery window.Thats what im trying to achieve

Comment: So, instead of using an anchor, use `<input type="submit" value="Pay Now">`

Comment: Also you must use `GET` in your form tag, not `POST` if you want it to use URL parameters.

Comment: @Loenix I know its not an head section.What would you do if you want to give your clients a button  which can be embedded on their weboages just by adding this?and on clicking on it a modal window with speceic href opens.The client shall not add anything else.Just this anchor tag.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. To begin with, your should contain the Javascript and CSS outside the anchor tag.

Comment: @RCorrie But can I add the links for css and js to this input submit button,so that the href opens in a modal window?

Comment: You should add the url into a hidden input field, this will get passed through on submit. Then inside the modal window's iframe, just drop in the url using PHP. But I still don't have a clear picture of what you want to achieve. I need a little more context.

Comment: @Rcorrie Can you check this? https://www.wepay.com/developer/buttons/buynow  Click on the button,a payment form will open.They are using a script inside the anchor tag

Comment: No, there isn't anything inside the anchors other than text.

Comment: @Rcorrie As you see on the link I showed.Im trying to open a payment form like that and also post some parameter to it

Comment: You can just use a script tag with the tag you want (not inside the other) and add what you want in the head section or in the body, just using the magic of jQuery.

Comment: @RCorrie Ok  if use the script and css outside the anchor tag will it work,I mean the modal window?

Comment: can you please show me  the parameter posting part?

Comment: I gave an answer and added comments just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how I would achieve this:

HTML

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return openModal()">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="price" value="100.00">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Pay Now">
</form>

<div id="modal" style="display:none"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function openModal(){
    // when you click the submit button
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        // Add an iframe inside the modal window, throw in the form value into the src URL
        $('#modal').html('<iframe src="http://www.domain.com/checkout.php?price=' + $('.price').val() + '"></iframe>');
        // Display the modal window
        $('#modal').show();
    }
    // Don't submit this form (we don't want the page to reload)
    return false;
}
```

So inside the iframe's source file, you would just need to grab the URL parameters and calculate them.

This is a simple example, no where near as involved as the example link you provided (they are using Ajax calls to achieve this), but this should get you started.